# (android) Edittext in actionbar fragment

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-edittext, fragment

I have an edittext in my actionbar. But when I switch to another fragment, the edittext stays.
I want to have the edittext only in one fragment.
Plus it seems to hide the actiobar title :/
Please help me. (Thanks)

This is my code :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
{ 
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_tab1, menu); 
    ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    // add the custom view to the action bar
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search);
    search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.search_user);

    search.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() 
    {

      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
          KeyEvent event) 
      {
          try
          {
                  //TASKS
              }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
            Toast.makeText(Tab1.this.getActivity(), "Problem. Please restart the app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
          return false;
      }
    });
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting you a simple example of an activity with 3 tabs each represented by a fragment. Each fragment adds it's own items to the action bar. First fragment adds icon, second fragment adds edittext view, third fragment adds nothing. When particular fragment is visible only that fragment action item is visible on action bar.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.user.actionbartabs;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
        // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
        // a reference to the Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
            // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
            // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
            // this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                case 2:
                    return "Section 3".toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        private int sectionNumber;

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            sectionNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach (Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onActivityCreated(bundle);
            ((TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.section_label)).setText(Integer.toString(sectionNumber));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            switch(sectionNumber) {
                case 1:
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_section1, menu);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_section2, menu);
                    EditText editText = (EditText) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings));
                    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
                        {
                            //Do something here
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case 3:
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_section3, menu);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            //Set action bar title
            ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Section " + sectionNumber);
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

action_item_edit_text.xml

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/editInput"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:hint="Write something"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="#BBBBBB"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:padding="6dp"/>
```

menu_section1.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha"
         app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

menu_section2.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"  app:actionLayout="@layout/action_item_edit_text"
         app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

menu_section3.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

</menu>
```

Note that since API level 21 using tabs with action bar is deprecated, so you may want to disable them and only stick to view pager. I posted example with tabs because you mentioned them in your question.